# Loading .ui files in PyQt5 causes delays

Tags: python, performance, pyqt5, qt-designer

I'm developing a project with PyQt5, and I'm having problems with the UI. I created the interface with Qt Designer, generated the .ui file, imported the code, and showed the window I wanted on the screen. However, I have a problem. There is a second delay in displaying the window on the screen.

Here is the .ui file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Form</class>
 <widget class="QWidget" name="Form">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>461</width>
    <height>320</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Form</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>20</x>
     <y>20</y>
     <width>47</width>
     <height>13</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>TextLabel</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>180</x>
     <y>280</y>
     <width>75</width>
     <height>25</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>PushButton</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>120</x>
     <y>60</y>
     <width>80</width>
     <height>25</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_2">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>220</x>
     <y>60</y>
     <width>80</width>
     <height>25</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_3">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>320</x>
     <y>60</y>
     <width>80</width>
     <height>25</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_4">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>20</x>
     <y>60</y>
     <width>80</width>
     <height>25</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QLabel" name="label_2">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>310</x>
     <y>70</y>
     <width>47</width>
     <height>13</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>-</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QLabel" name="label_3">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>110</x>
     <y>70</y>
     <width>47</width>
     <height>13</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>-</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QLabel" name="label_4">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>210</x>
     <y>70</y>
     <width>47</width>
     <height>13</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>-</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Here is the .py file:

```python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'uifiles/untitled.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.9
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sys

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(461, 320)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 20, 47, 13))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 280, 75, 25))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 60, 80, 25))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 60, 80, 25))
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.lineEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.lineEdit_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(320, 60, 80, 25))
        self.lineEdit_3.setObjectName("lineEdit_3")
        self.lineEdit_4 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.lineEdit_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 60, 80, 25))
        self.lineEdit_4.setObjectName("lineEdit_4")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(310, 70, 47, 13))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 70, 47, 13))
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 70, 47, 13))
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Form", "TextLabel"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "PushButton"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("Form", "-"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("Form", "-"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("Form", "-"))


class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget,Ui_Form):

    def __init__(self):

        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self)
        Ui_Form.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)

def main():

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    m = Window()

    m.show()

    app.exec()


if __name__ == "__main__":

    main()
```

Here is the print of how the screen stays when the delay occurs, approximately 1 to 2 seconds to generate the interface:

[image: Window with delay]

And here is the full screen:

[image: Window with all Widgets set]

I noticed that any delay is in `self.retranslateUi(Form)` or if I try to set `setupUi()` object's characteristics as `setText()` or connect a project with a signal.

If I comment the call of the function `retranslateUi()` in `setupUi()`,  everything occurs "well" - the window is executed without any delay, but the information of the widgets is not set.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this problem when using python 3.6.2, qt 5.9.1 and pyqt 5.9 on linux.

Comment: This can be lack of memory?

Comment: Are you using any IDE to run this ? Did you try using `uic.loadUi("main_window.ui")` to see if the problem persists ? I can't seem to reproduce this delay either.

Comment: The IDE i'am using is PyCharm, i have freezed this script with Cx_Freeze, and with the .exe the problem persist, I will try in anothet machine, maybe can be my PC. And i will try loadUi instead loadUiType

Comment: @daegontaven Same problem with loadUi function.

Comment: @JardelMatias. Try executing the script with python in a command window. Do not use an IDE or Cx_Freeze. Just run the script on its own.

Comment: @JardelMatias Yes, try it on another machine without Cx_Freeze. It could be Cx_Freeze causing the problem.

Comment: @ekhumoro I have tried that, same problem.

Comment: @daegontaven The load time reduces, but still have a delay. I friend mine is facing the same problem.

Comment: @JardelMatias I'm not sure then. It must be your machines, because I'm not facing that problem. Try using virtualenv on your friends machine just to be sure. Is your friend also running Windows ? Try a linux distro also.